# Проблема при создании exe-шников в python. Импорт всех библиотек и огромный вес файла

Tags: python, импорт, exe

Пытаюсь создать простенькую программу для работы с qr-кодами.
Вот код программы:

```
import qrcode


text = input("Введите текст для создания qr-кода:\n")
file_name = input("Введите название фала для записи qr-кода:\n")

img = qrcode.make(text)
img.save(file_name)
```

При запуске программы через консоль - всё работает. Я создаю exe-шник с помощью `pyinstaller -F --upx-dir=D:\upx-3.95-win64 script.py` и возникает проблема: exe-шник весит 127 мб (несмотря на сжатие UPX).

Насколько я понимаю, pyinstaller рекурсивно импортирует все библиотеки, которые импортируются в скрипте. Неужели модуль qrcode так много тянет за собой? Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно явно указать pyinstaller какие библиотеки импортировать? Согласно документации(https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/usage.html) опция --add-data - позволяет добавить библиотеки для импорта, но также она ипортирует и всё остальное. Можно запретить импортировать другие библиотеки (--exclude-module), но это значит перебирать все библиотеки и для каждой писать эту опцию? Мне кажется, что я делаю что-то неправильно...
Буду благодарен за помощь. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: `1) Exe-шник весит 211 мб.`, конечно, ведь: интерпретатор + все модули из коробки и внешние используемые + dll. Все библиотеки, это включая всякие дополнительные, что были через pip установлено, но при этом не используемые в самом скрипте? `2)` такое не должно быть, выведите в print `f"qr {qr_text} > {file_name}"`, проверьте что строка правильная. Кст, зачем вам тут питон, если тоже самое можно обычным батником сделать? `Можно ли уменьшить объём?` гуглите `pyinstaller upx`

Comment: Вы думаете, что батник решит мою задачу? А как он будет запускаться на других ПК, где нет модуля qrcode?

Comment: То, что вы используете модуль видно только по импорту `import qrcode`, но саму работу делает `qr`, что вы вызываете в `popen`. Тогда непонятно зачем вам `qrcode` и почему бы не таскать с батником `qr`. Если не прав, то не обессудьте -- что увидел в вопросе, про то и сказал... А насчет вашей проблемы с размером, я как-то попал в жесткие рамки размеров exe -- нужно было влезть в 10 мб, тогда мне помог чистый питон (https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/ скачайте как архив ссылка с текстом `embeddable zip file`), ручное добавление внешних модулей и upx. Костыльно, но выбирать не приходилось :)

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду опцию --add-data pyinstaller'a ? Разве она не добавляет к основному импорту дополнительные модули?

Comment: Если вы уточняете про то ручное добавление внешних модулей, то нет -- просто закинул в папку pip и установил в него нужные модули